# SwiftUI View not updating when @ObservedObject changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, property-wrapper-published

I have a location manager class that looks like this:

```
final class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var location: CLLocation?
    @Published var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus
    @Published var totalDistance: CGFloat
    @Published var locationData: String
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager

    ...
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let latestLocation = locations.last else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let currentLocation = self.location {
                let distance = latestLocation.distance(from: currentLocation)
                self.totalDistance += distance
                self.location = latestLocation
                self.locationData = String(format: "%.5f", latestLocation.coordinate.latitude) + ", " + String(format: "%.5f", latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                print("location: \(self.locationData), distance: \(self.totalDistance)") //I see coordinates continuously printed here, so I know the location data is getting updated
        } else {
            self.location = latestLocation
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Then, I have a view model that has this:

```
@ObservedObject var locationManager : LocationManager //I tried @Published here too, to no avail.

init() {
    let localLocationManager = LocationManager()        
    self.locationManager = localLocationManager
}
```

And a view like this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
...
VStack {
    Text("TEST DATA")
    Text("Location: \(viewModel.locationManager.locationData)")
    Text("distance traveled: \(viewModel.locationManager.totalDistance)")
}
```

However none of this text gets updated when the user's location changes. What am I missing? Other `@Published` properties in my view model do cause the view to update.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `@ObservedObject`. You should be using `@StateObject` and remove your `init`. Secondly, nested ObservableObjects don't work, so `MyViewModel` doesn't know to update when a property on `locationManager` changes unless you explicitly send `objectWillChange` to the parent object.

Comment: Thanks. Was able to get it working by using `objectWillChange`